# Relation among generators of kernel of the symmetrization map

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $K$ be a field, and consider the $3$-dimensional vector space $V$ over $K$ with basis $x$, $y$, $z$. Then $V^{\otimes 3}$ has dimension $3^3=27$ and the symmetrization $\operatorname{Sym}^3(V)$ has dimension ${5\choose 3}=10$, so the kernel of the projection map $V^{\otimes 3}\twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{Sym}^3(V)$ has dimension $17$. I can list $18$ elements that span the kernel: take one of the three commutators $[x,y]$, $[x,z]$, or $[y,z]$ (which live in $V^{\otimes 2}$), and tensor either on the left or on the right with $x$, $y$, or $z$. So these $18$ elements should satisfy a unique (up to scaling) linear relation.

Is there a way to see what this relation is without writing down a giant matrix and row reducing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think in $S_3$ (permutation group on $3$ elements).
The element $(12)(23)$ has order $3$, hence
\begin{align}
(23)=(12)(23)(12)(23)(12)
\end{align}
Consequently, we have
\begin{align}
x\otimes(y\otimes z-z\otimes y)
&=(x\otimes y-y\otimes x)\otimes z\\
&+y\otimes(x\otimes z-z\otimes x)\\
&+(y\otimes z-z\otimes y)\otimes x\\
&+z\otimes(y\otimes x-x\otimes y)\\
&+(z\otimes x-x\otimes z)\otimes y
\end{align}